# Windows Batch Script

Tags: command-line, batch-file

How for the life of me can I pass a space at the windows command line that happens to be in a folder name? When I remove the space from the folder name, I can execute a directory copy. I've googled escaping spaces, etc., but I just haven't hit on it yet.

Thanks for your help on this one!

Comment: use quotes and watch the magic.

Comment: Thanks! Figured on trying that after I posted this. WOOOT.

Answer (score 0):

Using quotations will solve this issue. Here is an example.

```
 C:\Users\Administrator>copy "C:\users\Administrator\desktop\new folder" "C:\users\Administrator"
 The command completed successfully.

 C:\Users\Administrator>
```

I hope this helps.